# I have JSON data coming from a basic auth API and want to extract certain data(s) from HttpResponse<String> response using JAVA

Tags: java, api

```
// Concatenate Username and password and use base64 to encode the concatenated string
    String plainCredentials = username + ":" + password;
    String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredentials.getBytes()));
    // Create authorization header
    String authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64Credentials;
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                .uri(URI.create("https://zccemmanuel.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets"))
                                .GET()
                                .header("Authorization", authorizationHeader)
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .build();
     // Send HTTP request
                        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

I understand response.body displays all the info after it has been turned into a string. I want to retrieve some data(s) instead of the whole thing.

```
 System.out.println(response.body());
```

Comment: You need to parse the string to get the parts you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying but can you give me a heads up of what that'll look like or point me to the right direction @Code-Apprentice

Comment: You can google "parse json java" for some lots more information.